# What is Saccus in Embryology?

Tags: homework, embryology, etymology

The word seems to be of German origin.
I have it here

> Saccus lymphaticus inguinalis,
>   Saccus lymphaticus jugularis,
>   Saccus lymphaticus posterior,
>   Saccus lymphaticus retroperitonaealis.

I would like to use the word "sinus" instead.
However, Google search does not give good results for it.

**What is the meaning of the word "saccus" here?**

Comment: From the Latin saccus, bag, which is in turn from the Ancient Greek sakkos, sack or bag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saccus simply means sac or bag and is is closed cavity. The lymph nodes develop from the structures, see this image:

[image]

1. Superior cardinal vein (jugular vein)
2. Jugular lymphatic sacs
3. Right subclavian vein
4. Axillary lymphatic sacs
5. Left brachiocephalic vein
6. Thoracic duct (bilateral)
7. Lumbar lymphatic sacs
8. Iliac lymphatic sacs

The image is taken from this [webpage](http://www.embryology.ch/anglais/pcardio/lymph01.html), which should be interesting for you.